# Always mobile menu, Rails 5, bootstrap-rubygem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am using `Rails 5` with `Twitter Bootstrap gem` (Twitter Bootstrap 4.00.beta2.1). I am using Carousels and Grid system and everything works, but not navbar. I am using code for navbar for Bootstrap site [Bootstrap site](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/) and is always in mobile state.

I tried with new page with Bootstrap not with `bootstrap-rubygem`, but from CDN and the navbar works fine. For the example in page with `bootstrap-rubygem` I see:

```
.collapse {
    display: none;
}
```

In the page with `Bootstrap` from `CDN`, I see same rule, but another CSS override it:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) _navbar.scss:162
    .navbar-toggleable-md .navbar-collapse {
        display: -webkit-box!important;
        display: -webkit-flex!important;
        display: -ms-flexbox!important;
        display: flex!important;
        width: 100%;
}
```

And in the page with `bootstrap-rubygem`, I can't see rules for `@media (min-width: 992px)`

What I can do ?

Comment: define a `bootstrap_and_overrides.css` file and override the css there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changed on 4.0.0-beta

*Update navbar responsive behaviors to be mobile first, use a new class name .navbar-expand instead of .navbar-toggleable, remove toggler position modifiers (relies on flex utils now), and fix a handful of bugs.*

```
# _navbar.html.slim
nav.navbar.navbar-light.bg-white.navbar-expand-md
```

Follow the official release notes for changes, the rubygem doesn't have much info https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases

Comment: PD: that docs are partially obsolete, the new ones are in the main subdomain(if that makes sense lol) http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/